# Вопрос к предложно-падежной форме имени существительного

Tags: синтаксис, падежи, вопрос

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой вопрос (какой? или чей?) лучше всего задать к существительному в Р.п. в следующих словосочетаниях: *тираж **календаря**, редакция  **календаря**, предшественник  **книги**,недочетах **издания***.
Если родительный падеж приименный, со значением количества, то вопрос будет "какой?" или "чего?", например: тысячи писем, миллионы людей, стакан молока, килограмм фруктов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     Какой вопрос (какой? или чей?) лучше всего задать к существительному в Р.п. в 
     следующих словосочетаниях: тираж календаря, редакция календаря,
     предшественник книги, недочетах издания.
```

Давайте поразмышляем. Вообще-то вопрос чей? задают к притяжательным прилагательным, но значение принадлежности может быть и у имени существительного: хвост лисицы = лисицын хвост. У каких названных Вами существительных есть значение принадлежности?

*Тираж календаря = календарный тираж* (как книжный тираж) - да, есть, возможен **вопрос чей?** На вопрос какой тираж? скорее ответом будет большой / маленький.

Редакция календаря - здесь принадлежности я не вижу. Более того, и вопрос какая? здесь не подходит, на мой взгляд, это не определение, а дополнение, если, конечно, это не в значении "редакционная группа". Если это отглагольное существительное, преобразуем в глагольную форму: *редакция словаря - редактировать словарь*. Несогласованное определение при преобразовании в глагольные формы  является обстоятельством: сон до утра → спать как долго? – до утра. У нас же дополнение. Следовательно, это **дополнение и вопрос - чего?**

*Предшественник книги = книжный предшественник*, это определение и возможен **вопрос чей?**, есть оттенок принадлежности (её предшественник).

*О недочётах издания* - преобразовываем: недочёты в издании (где? в чём?) предложно-падежная форма, следовательно, это определение, вопрос **о каких недочётах?**

**О чьих недочётах?** мы бы спросили в сочетании *о недочётах издательства или издателей*.

Родительный падеж приименный со значением количества - это всё-таки **дополнение** со значением части чего-то: *тысячи (чего?) писем, миллионы (кого?) людей, стакан (чего?) молока, килограмм (чего?) фруктов.*